# Document buttons returning as null until selected?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to write a simple page for a form, but the radio buttons are misbehaving with my javascript. I want only one of each tier to be selected at once, requiring some code that checks and unchecks radio buttons, but the first time it tries to set the value it gets an error saying it cant set the value of a null object. Any insight people can give would be amazing.

P.S. my coding is horrible and has no comments, I know, I'm sorry.

```js
currentValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function checkVote(place, value) {
  if (document.getElementById("p" + place + value).checked === true) {
    oldNum = currentValues[place - 1]
    oldPlace = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (currentValues[i] === value) {
        oldPlace = i + 1;
        currentValues[i] = oldNum
      }
    }
    currentValues[place - 1] = value
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      document.getElementById("p" + (i + 1) + currentValues[i]).checked = true
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p11">1:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote1" value="1" onclick="checkVote(1, this.value)" id="p11" checked="checked"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p12">2:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote1" value="2" onclick="checkVote(1, this.value)" id="p12"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p13">3:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote1" value="3" onclick="checkVote(1, this.value)" id="p13"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p14">4:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote1" value="4" onclick="checkVote(1, this.value)" id="p14"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p15">5:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote1" value="5" onclick="checkVote(1, this.value)" id="p15"><br><br>

<label class="ratingPoints" for="p21">1:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote2" value="1" onclick="checkVote(2, this.value)" id="p21"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p22">2:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote2" value="2" onclick="checkVote(2, this.value)" id="p22" checked="checked"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p23">3:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote2" value="3" onclick="checkVote(2, this.value)" id="p23"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p24">4:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote2" value="4" onclick="checkVote(2, this.value)" id="p24"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p25">5:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote2" value="5" onclick="checkVote(2, this.value)" id="p25"><br><br>

<label class="ratingPoints" for="p31">1:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote3" value="1" onclick="checkVote(3, this.value)" id="p31"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p32">2:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote3" value="2" onclick="checkVote(3, this.value)" id="p32"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p33">3:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote3" value="3" onclick="checkVote(3, this.value)" id="p33" checked="checked"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p34">4:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote3" value="4" onclick="checkVote(3, this.value)" id="p34"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p35">5:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote3" value="5" onclick="checkVote(3, this.value)" id="p35"><br><br>

<label class="ratingPoints" for="p41">1:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote4" value="1" onclick="checkVote(4, this.value)" id="p41"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p42">2:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote4" value="2" onclick="checkVote(4, this.value)" id="p42"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p43">3:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote4" value="3" onclick="checkVote(4, this.value)" id="p43"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p44">4:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote4" value="4" onclick="checkVote(4, this.value)" id="p44" checked="checked"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p45">5:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote4" value="5" onclick="checkVote(4, this.value)" id="p45"><br><br>

<label class="ratingPoints" for="p51">1:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote5" value="1" onclick="checkVote(5, this.value)" id="p51"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p52">2:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote5" value="2" onclick="checkVote(5, this.value)" id="p52"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p53">3:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote5" value="3" onclick="checkVote(5, this.value)" id="p53"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p54">4:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote5" value="4" onclick="checkVote(5, this.value)" id="p54"><br>
<label class="ratingPoints" for="p55">5:</label>
<input class="ratingPoints" type="radio" name="vote5" value="5" onclick="checkVote(5, this.value)" id="p55" checked="checked"><br>
```

The program automatically starts with each row of buttons checked in their column order (column 1 has button 1 selected, column 2 has row 2 etc), so if I were to select column 1 row 2, I would expect column 2, row 1 to select and column 2 row 1 to deselect. In actuality, I have to select each button before it will be checked, until then it just says cannot modify a null object.

Comment: Could you please show what error are you getting? because I ran the same code but did not get any error. Please check it here https://playcode.io/1047737

Comment: You're mentioning columns. Should the radio buttons be displayed in a 5 by 5 grid? The reason I'm asking - if I understand your issue correctly, whenever you choose an option from one column, you want whatever has that option chosen in another column to switch places? For example, if the first column has the first option clicked, and I click on 13 (first column, third option), then whatever has the third option checked should switch to its first option?

Answer (score 0):

In which browser do you have this problem? I can not reproduce this with Chromium 108. Try wrapping the line where it throws the error in a try-catch block.

Also you could just initialize your state by manually calling your checkVote function N times with the proper inital state.